# Documentation/references on how ROS works internally?

Tags: ros, documentation

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hey,
I am doing a project for my Uni involving ROS and in one of the chapters of the thesis I should talk about the state-of-the-art of ROS (i.e. how it really works internally).
Are there any documents that describe this? In the papers section I can only find information about specific experiments, not the ROS system itself.

Cheers,

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29260/documentation/references-on-how-ros-works-internally?/) by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on ROS Answers with karma: 385 on 2012-03-06

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You have this information in the ROS wiki http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Introduction also there is the paper [ROS: an open-source Robot Operating System](http://ai.stanford.edu/%7Eang/papers/icraoss09-ROS.pdf).
I hope this is what you need!

---

Originally posted by [martimorta](https://answers.ros.org/users/69/martimorta/) with karma: 843 on 2012-03-06

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jlo](https://answers.ros.org/users/1132/jlo/) on 2012-03-06**:
Yes! That's great. In the introduction part I found the parts for Technical overview and High level concepts highly useful.
Thanks!